# Color each label of Excel bar graph differently

Tags: vba, excel

I have a horizontal bar graph, where I would like to color each of the labels differently. Currently, I can only set one color to all of them. I am looking for some VBA code, which can help me achieve this.
Can anyone please tell me if this is possible? If yes, how do I get to access each of these labels differently.

Comment: If someone does vote the question with a negative rating, please also have the courtesy to leave a comment as to why you did so. I feel it's a perfectly reasonable question to ask, that whether an Excel feature exists or not, and I did do research before asking it here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need VBA, or do you just need to know how to do it in general?

In general, if you click once on a bar, you select the whole series of bars. If you click again, you select the individual bar, and you can then format it. It's not a double click, it's two single clicks.

But if you really need VBA, it would go something like this:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    .Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
    '' etc.
End With
```